# How can I beta test an Universal Windows Platform Application?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, beta-testing

How can I beta test an `Universal Windows Platform` Application? I can install it on my own device, and anyone else who gives me device. But how can I provide the application to external testers using just their email address?

So, Is there any way to do a specific user release via the `Windows Store` or any other `Wireless Distribution` stuff for beta testing?

Comment: On the Pricing and availability page, choose Hide this app and prevent acquisition. Customers with a promotional code can still download it on Windows 10 devices in the Distribution and visibility section. This prevents anyone from finding your app in the Store via searching or browsing. More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are options in the Windows store to hide your app for public but make it available for your specific testers. here is the guide:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution

you could also look at [Hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/) which has a beta app store although this works best for testing with internal users.

Comment: Hockeyapp is awesome but going with `Windows Store` beta testing. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @VineetChoudhary Actually HockeyApp has one thing that Microsoft Store and Partner Center don't and that is the Recruitment feature. Simply put a a special link on say Facebook or Twitter and upon clicking, potential testers can sign-up and download.  Or you can have them apply for access first.   MS Store, Partner Center  and App Center for that matter require that you know peoples' email address ahead of time. https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-invite-beta-testers

Comment: @VineetChoudhary Also don't get burnt by **Private Audience** in Partner Center. _"[The Private audience option can only be used when you have not already published your app to a public audience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution)"_.  It seems a bit silly to me that alpha and beta versions still have to go through the whole certification process when at the end of the day you just want your testers to gain access to it.  The Microsoft Store is an understandable but annoying blockage in this case.  HockeyApp is better for alpha/beta